# Backbone: Pass Model Attribute to a View returns undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var ShapeSizePoolView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $('#agpb_shape_size_body'),    
    tmpl : $('#tmpl_agpb_shape_size').html(),
    initialize : function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render : function() {
        var compiled_template = _.template( this.tmpl, this.model.toJSON() ),
            sizes = this.model.get('sizes');
        $(this.el).append( compiled_template );

        // this is used for our pool sizes
        for(var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
            console.log(sizes[i]);
            new ShapeSizePoolButtonView(
            { 
                size : sizes[i],
                el : $(this.el).find('.agpb_size_list')
            });
        }
    }
});

var ShapeSizePoolButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tmpl : $('.tmpl_agpb_shape_size_button').html(),
    initialize : function() {
        // this.render();
        console.log( this.size );
        },
        render : function() {
            var compiled_template = _.template( this.tmpl, this.sizes );
            $(this.el).append( compiled_template );
        }
});
```

this.model.get('sizes') returns an array of objects. If I console.log one of the objects in ShapeSizePoolView I get:

```
{
    id: "6", 
    dimensions: "12'",
    price: "649.99", 
    sort_order: "1"
}
```

I pass this object to a new view but if I console.log this.size from ShapeSizePoolButtonView I get:

```
undefined
```

Does anyone have an idea of where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

> When creating a new View, the options you pass — after being merged
>   into any default options already present on the view — are attached to
>   the view as this.options for future reference. There are several
>   special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the
>   view: model, collection, el, id, className, tagName and attributes.

So, you can access this custom option by using `this.options`:

```
var ShapeSizePoolButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tmpl : $('.tmpl_agpb_shape_size_button').html(),
    initialize : function() {
        // this.render();
        console.log( this.options.size ); // Not this.size
    },
    ....
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Lukas. I guess I should make sure I always read the manual :).

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `size` to the `View` constructor, but it will not get copied onto `this` automatically. You would need to add code like this:

```
var ShapeSizePoolButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize : function(options) {
    this.size = options.size;
    // this.render();
    console.log( this.size );
  },
```

Also, you are incorrectly using `this.sizes` instead of `this.size` in your render call.